# sqli only taking the first row from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to use php to display all the comments added to a form but it's only giving me the first row.
Any idea why this is happening?

```
    <?php

echo "Comments page";


$conn =  new mysqli('localhost', 'comment42_user', 'test42', 'comments');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT fname, lname, email, website, comment FROM comments;");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "First name:" . $row['fname'];
echo " last name:" . $row['lname'];
echo " Email:" . $row['email'];
echo " Website:" . $row['website'];
echo " comment:" . $row['comment'];


?>
```

Comment: you don't need `;` inside the query ()

Comment: Well you are only fetching one row. Check [mysqli::fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) examples.

Comment: you could loop and get at least the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the while statement:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
   echo "First name:" . $row['fname'];
   echo " last name:" . $row['lname'];
   echo " Email:" . $row['email'];
   echo " Website:" . $row['website'];
   echo " comment:" . $row['comment'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm fairly new to php.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `while` loop to display all comments.

Try

```
<?php

echo "Comments page";


$conn =  new mysqli('localhost', 'comment42_user', 'test42', 'comments');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT fname, lname, email, website, comment FROM comments;");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "First name:" . $row['fname'];
    echo " last name:" . $row['lname'];
    echo " Email:" . $row['email'];
    echo " Website:" . $row['website'];
    echo " comment:" . $row['comment'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting more than 1 row put the echo in a while or foreach loop

```
<?php

echo "Comments page";


$conn =  new mysqli('localhost', 'comment42_user', 'test42', 'comments');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT fname, lname, email, website, comment FROM comments;");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "First name:" . $row['fname'];
echo " last name:" . $row['lname'];
echo " Email:" . $row['email'];
echo " Website:" . $row['website'];
echo " comment:" . $row['comment'];
}

?>
```